# Is it possible to combine multiple tasks results in one data entry using Kafka?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, message-queue

Imagine the system got an order as a JSON input. The order requires multiple tasks to be processed - some of them require local data processing, some - require responses from external API, etc., so each type of task has different time estimations. Each task output provides JSON output, including order id.

So, I added all of these tasks to Kafka, and they're getting processed. The question is - how to combine all of them, based on the order id, when the last order's task is processed?

If I'm missing some logic or picking the wrong tool (tool X will fit better) - let me know. Any topic/stream-based advice will do.

Comment: Got an answer on a Russian-speaking QA site: https://qna.habr.com/q/884649. Ping me, if you need a translation.

Comment: Kafka is the wrong tool for this. Look at temporal.io which solves this type of problem trivially.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka is not the right tool for what you want. While it is possible to build your app using it and a database, it would require a lot of custom code.

Consider using an orchestrator like [temporal.io](https://temporal.io) that out of the box solves your requirement.